# onepreexecute doesn't recognize outer class variable

Tags: android

First, i am a newbie in android. The problem is that onpreexecute method recognizes outer class variables finalnomos and finalcity but isn't recognize startnomos and startcity variables returning nulls in Logcat.
1. Why is that strange behavior given that startnomos and startcity are similar to finalnomos and finalcityq
2. Can you provide a successful code change that is going to work;

Part of my code ( the significant part...)

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

             startnomos = data.getStringExtra("strnom1");
             startcity = data.getStringExtra("strct1");
             Log.d("startnomos", startnomos);
             Log.d("startcity", startcity);

        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == 3) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            finalnomos = data.getStringExtra("fnlnom1");
            finalcity = data.getStringExtra("fnlcity1");
             Log.d("finalnomos", finalnomos);
             Log.d("finalcity", finalcity);

        }
    }
    }


static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
int yr, mon, day;
int hour, min;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    yr = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mon = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour = today.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    min = today.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, yr, mon, day);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeSetListener, hour, min, true);
    }
    return null;
}

  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        yr = year;
        mon = monthOfYear + 1;
        day = dayOfMonth;
        depDate1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depDate1);
        depDate1.setText(day + " - " + mon + " - " + yr);
    }

};

  private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        hour = hourOfDay;
        min = minute;
        depTime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.depTime1);
        depTime1.setText(hour + " : " + min);

    }

};




public void onClick(View btnregidiot) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new RegisterIdiot().execute();

}


class RegisterIdiot extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        eidmet1 = eidosmetaf1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        w1 = weight.getText().toString();
        dpDt1 = depDate1.getText().toString();
        dpTm1 = depTime1.getText().toString();
        exdyp1 = exeidypeir1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        comments = comments2.getText().toString();


        Log.d("eidmet1", eidmet1);
        Log.d("w1", w1);
        Log.d("fnlnom1", ""+finalnomos);
        Log.d("fnlcity1", ""+finalcity);
        Log.d("dpDt1", dpDt1);
        Log.d("dpTm1", dpTm1);
        Log.d("exdyp1", exdyp1);
        Log.d("comments", comments);
        Log.d("strnom1", "" +startnomos);
        Log.d("strct1", "" +startcity);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they are in if - else statement and if finalnomos and finalcity have value startnomos and startcity do not have value and are null, because your  onActivityResult called when you come from some intent and you can not have 2 intent at the same time, or your code says so.